# Linux - How to remove certain lines from a files based on a field value

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cut

I want to remove certain lines from a **tab-delimited** file and write output to a new file.

```
a   b   c   2017-09-20
a   b   c   2017-09-19
es  fda d   2017-09-20
es  fda d   2017-09-19
```

The 4th column is Date, basically I want to keep only lines that has 4th column as "2017-09-19" (keep line 2&4) and write to a new file.  The new file should have same format as the raw file.

How to write the linux command for this example?

**Note**: The search criteria should be on the 4th field as I have other fields in the real data and possibly have same value as 4th field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} $4=="2017-09-19"' file
```

> `OFS`: output field separator, a space by default

Comment: I tried that code, however the output returns 4 lines and all of the 4th field is "2017-09-19".  It does not filter out the line 1&3 which 4th field is "2017-09-20"

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} $4=="2017-09-19"' file    this code returns only line 4.  Line 2 was filtered out somehow.

Comment: Check your file for special characters with `cat -A file` or `cat -v file`.

Comment: As shown by @ashawley you can omit `BEGIN{OFS="\t"}`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I found my created sample files has ^M at end of line, because I edit the sample data in notepad+ and hit Enter for next line, then copy to linux, that is a CR.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` to filter:

```
cat file.txt | grep '2017-09-19' > filtered_file.txt
```

This is not perfect, since the string `2017-09-19` is not required to appear in the 4th column, but if your file looks like the example, it'll work.

Comment: Thanks, that code is working on this example. But my real issue is the search criteria should be on 4th field, because I have other fields in the real data.

Comment: You can anchor at end of line with `grep '2017-09-19$'`.

Answer (score 1):

Sed solution:

```
sed -nr "/^([^\t]*\t){3}2017-09-19/p" input.txt >output.txt
```

this is:

- `-n` - don't output every line
- `-r` - extended regular expresion
- `/regexp/p` - print line that contains regular expression *regexp*
- `^` - begin of line
- `(regexp){3}` - repeat regexp 3 times
- `[^\t]` - any character except tab
- `\t` - tab character
- `*` - repeat characters multiple times
- `2017-09-19` - search text

That is, skip 3 columns separated by a tab from the beginning of the line, and then check that the value of column 4 coincides with the required value.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/2017-09-19/' file >newfile

cat newfile
a   b   c   2017-09-19
es  fda d   2017-09-19
```